# Download image with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, imagedownload

I'm new to python. I have to download some images from the web and save it to my local file system. I've noticed that the response content does not contain any image data.
The problem only occurs with this specific url, with every other image url the code works fine.

I know the easiest solution would be just use another url but still i'd  like to ask if someone had a similar problem.

```
import requests
    url = 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png'
    filename = "bitcoin.png"

    response = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    response.raw.decode_content = True
    with open(f'images/{filename}', 'wb') as outfile:
       outfile.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look at the content of the response with `response.text`, you'll see the website blocked your request.

> Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.

Then, you can try to check if changing the [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) of your request fixes your issue.

```py
response = requests.get(
    url, 
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36',
    },
    stream = True
)
```

If it doesn't, you may need to get your data with something which can parse javascript like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/).

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding the header to the request has worked for me